# How to find $\delta$ such that $ \delta \log \frac{1}{\delta} + (1-\delta) \log \frac{1}{1-\delta} < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$?

Tags: probability, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, entropy

Consider a random variable $$X = \begin{cases}x_0:&\text{with probability } \delta \\ x_1:& \text{with probability } 1-\delta \end{cases}$$ The entropy of $X$ is $$H(X) = \delta \log \frac{1}{\delta} + (1-\delta) \log \frac{1}{1-\delta}$$

**How can we show that for all $\epsilon>0$, we can always find a $\delta > 0$ such that $H(X) < \epsilon$?**

I'm not able to find a way to do this cleanly. For example, I've tried playing around with setting $\delta = c \epsilon$ for different values of $c$ (such as $\delta = \epsilon, \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1000}$, etc) but I haven't been able to find a way to find the appropriate $\delta$ or $c$ that would do this.

Some other approaches I had included using the log-sum inequality ($\sum_i a_i \log \frac{a_i}{b_i} \geq (\sum_i a_i) \log \frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}$) and other bounds on $\log \delta$ such as $1-\frac{1}{\delta} \leq \ln x \leq \delta-1$, but the best I've been able to do has been to show that $H(X) \leq 1$, which isn't useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

If you want to find a good bound for the solution $\delta \in (0, 1/2)$ of the equation $\delta \log \frac{1}{\delta} + (1-\delta) \log \frac{1}{1-\delta} = \epsilon$, here are some thoughts.

Let $\epsilon \in (0, \ln 2)$.

It is easy to prove that, for all $\delta \in (0, 1)$,
$$(1 - \delta)\ln\frac{1}{1  - \delta} \le \delta.$$
(*Note*: Simply use $\ln u \le u - 1$.)

Thus, we have, for all $\delta \in (0, 1)$,
$$\delta \ln \frac{1}{\delta} + (1-\delta) \ln \frac{1}{1-\delta} 
\le \delta \ln \frac{1}{\delta} + \delta.$$

The equation $\delta \ln \frac{1}{\delta} + \delta = \epsilon$ has exactly one real solution on $(0, 1)$, say
$$\delta_0 = \frac{\epsilon}{-W_{-1}(-\epsilon \mathrm{e}^{-1})}$$
where $W_{-1}(\cdot)$
is the Lambert W function.

We have, for all $\delta \in (0, \delta_0)$,
$$\delta \ln \frac{1}{\delta} + (1-\delta) \ln \frac{1}{1-\delta} < \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to proving that
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\delta \log\frac{1}{\delta}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{\delta \to 1^-} \delta \log\frac{1}{\delta} = 0$$

The second limit is trivial (just substitute $\delta = 1$ since the function is continuous). For the first one you can write $$\delta \log\frac{1}{\delta} = \frac{\log\frac{1}{\delta}}{\frac{1}{\delta}}$$
and use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: This is definitely proving the same thing as my original question, but I suppose I was looking more for an answer that described the algebraic manipulations needed to find an appropriate $\delta$ to bound $H(\delta)$ with respect to $\epsilon$. Maybe another way to put it is that while I can see that the limit of $H(\delta)$ approaches $0$, I'm curious how fast exactly it will go to $0$. I've modified the question title so that's hopefully clearer, sorry about the confusion.